# Ext 4.1 - How to get a reference to a class created with Ext.define()

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a class being created with a method like this:

```
Ext.define('MY.class.Manager', {
    ....
    ....
    ....
    manageStuff: function(){


    }
}
```

Originally, I only needed the `manageStuff` function in one place, so everything was fine.  Now though, I have added another class and I need to be able to call the `manageStuff` function from within the new class.

I have tried to get a reference in the new class:

```
var ManagerClass = Ext.getClass('MY.class.Manager');
```

And also:

```
var ManagerClass = Ext.getClass('class.Manager');
```

Both return `null`

Just to be sure that the Manager Class is being defined before I try to get it, I put in print statements:

They read as:

```
...making manager class
...getting manager class
```

Looking for any help because I am sure my approach to this problem is not even correct to begin with.

Comment: If two classes are using the same method, you should probably put that method into a common parent of the two classes (assuming the classes are related), or make it be a static method that is accessible by both classes (you can add a namespace to the global namespace, and put the method in it)

Comment: They are unrelated so I would prefer to make it static and accessible to both.  How would I go about doing that/making a namespace with Ext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the method globally accessible, so both classes can use it. First, if you don't have a global namespace already, you can create one with Ext using `Ext.namespace`. In this example, I will make `MY` be the namespace all your global variables and methods will be contained in, and `MY.helper` where your helper methods (like `manageStuff`) will be contained in.

```
Ext.namespace(
    'MY',
    'MY.helper',
    // more namespaces inside 'MY' as needed ...
);
```

And then you can declare you helper method:

```
MY.helper.manageStuff = function() {
    // do stuff...
};
```

And now you can use this method (and anything else stored inside `MY`) anywhere in your application.

```
Ext.define('MY.class.Manager', {
    //...
    //...

    someFunctionThatCallsManageStuff: function(){
        MY.helper.managerStuff();
    }
});
```

Note: in javascript, you can store any variables inside the global namespace, and just call them directly, but I find that can clutter up the global namespace. Instead, I like to have a single variable that contains all my global variables. In this example, your single variable is `MY`. Then you can add "packages" to it to organize your globals, such as `MY.helper`.

Note 2: Using `Ext.namespace` in the example above is equivalent to the following:

```
//init MY as global variable
MY = {};
// add properties to MY
MY.helper = {};
// add properties to MY.helper
MY.helper.manageStuff = function() {
    // do stuff...
};
```

Comment: Reason for downvote: this way is not the best practice. See my answer.

Comment: True, in this case a mixin would probably be better. However, I've hit times where a mixin doesn't make a lot of sense to me, when a specific method is used all over the place. So, I think the info in my answer is still useful, even if it isn't best practice. Anyway, I'm curious what you would do for this scenerio: I have an app with tons of renderer functions, and I put them all in one file. Most of them are used in multiple different classes, and some of them are used in a ton of classes. What do you think the best design would be for this?

Answer (score 4):

To share behavioral traits between otherwise unrelated classes, use mixins:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.mixin.Foo', {
    foo: function(bar, baz) {
        alert(bar + ' ' + baz);
    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.class.Foo', {
    mixins: [
        'MyApp.mixin.Foo'
    ],

    methodThatCallsFoo: function(bar, baz) {
        this.foo(bar, baz); // foo method has been mixed in the
    }
});
```

This applies to Ext JS 4.x+; bear in mind that in Ext JS 5 this mechanism became even more powerful, see [Ext.Mixin doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Mixin).

Comment: The only problem I foresee with this is that the two classes I'm working with already exist and have many thousands of lines written.  I only need one function from class A to be accessible by class B, so I don't see how mixing in this case would be viable.  And the classes themselves aren't really object oriented in a way where mixing would make sense.